# Tomcat jdbc connection pool not enforcing testOnBorrow and/or validationQueryTimeout

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have an issue on a jdbc connection pool on Tomcat/7.0.8: It seems like it's not enforcing the testOnBorrow and/or validationQueryTimeout parameters.

---

The Tomcat server has the following JDBC resource defined:

```
<Resource
  name="jdbc/DataSource"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username="${DB_USERNAME}"
  password="${DB_PASSWORD}"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="0"
  maxWait="10000"
  initialSize="0"
  testOnBorrow="true"
  testOnConnect="true"
  validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
  validationQueryTimeout="5"
  suspectTimeout="600"
  removeAbandoned="true"
  removeAbandonedTimeout="600"
  logAbandoned="true"
  abandonWhenPercentageFull="100"
  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="600000"
  validationInterval="3000"

  jdbcInterceptors="StatementCache(prepared=true,callable=false,max=100)"
  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@remote-db-server.domain.com:1521/DB_NAME"
/>
```

---

Before introducing connectivity issues with the database, Tomcat process has 2 DB connections opened:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0     93 10.215.221.83:50126         10.215.221.154:1521         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     92 10.215.221.83:50160         10.215.221.154:1521         ESTABLISHED
```

---

Then, I introduce a database connectivity issue: I modify the route on the database server, so that it is no longer able to respond to the Tomcat server, and I send a few DB requests through the application running on Tomcat.

I see that the same 2 (no longer working) database connections remain open for 10-15 minutes, even though the database is no longer responding (as you see in the Send-Q parameter below - having values of 93 and 92):

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0     93 10.215.221.83:50126         10.215.221.154:1521         
ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     92 10.215.221.83:50160         10.215.221.154:1521         ESTABLISHED
```

I also see in a thread dump the 2 threads that are using the DB connections, as follows, and they are indeed in socketRead0, waiting after a response from the database:

```
"http-bio-8543-exec-6" #50 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3bb06fe000 nid=0x62a5 runnable [0x00007f3b38a13000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:426)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:390)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:766)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1026)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1718)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1678)
        - locked <0x00000006c3043008> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:332)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:483)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:394)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:794)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:648)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1425)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.getSecurityUserKey(Unknown Source)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.audit.impl.SecurityAuditFacadeImpl.auditLogout(SecurityAuditFacadeImpl.java:208)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.audit.AuditService.auditLogout(AuditService.java:164)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.manager.SecurityManager.logout(SecurityManager.java:573)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.authentication.CustomSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(CustomSessionListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:800)
        - locked <0x000000077fc73ce0> (a org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.invalidate(StandardSession.java:1264)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.invalidate(StandardSessionFacade.java:183)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.fraud.components.LogoutServlet.service(LogoutServlet.java:33)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.reporting.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.requestvalidator.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.authentication.tomcat.FFMAuthenticator.invoke(FFMAuthenticator.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        - locked <0x000000077cf30318> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

The 2 connections and threads remain in the same state for about 15 minutes, after which Tomcat finally logs an error and closes the connections:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
ERROR [com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.manager.SecurityManager] org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.audit.SecuirtyAuditException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.audit.AuditService.auditLogout(AuditService.java:167)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.manager.SecurityManager.logout(SecurityManager.java:573)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.authentication.CustomSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(CustomSessionListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.invalidate(StandardSession.java:1264)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.invalidate(StandardSessionFacade.java:183)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.fraud.components.LogoutServlet.service(LogoutServlet.java:33)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.reporting.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.requestvalidator.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.authentication.tomcat.FFMAuthenticator.invoke(FFMAuthenticator.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:430)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.getSecurityUserKey(Unknown Source)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.audit.impl.SecurityAuditFacadeImpl.auditLogout(SecurityAuditFacadeImpl.java:208)
        at com.fairisaac.edm.cc.security.audit.AuditService.auditLogout(AuditService.java:164)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1425)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.reconnect(PooledConnection.java:315)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:813)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:648)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:162)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)
        ... 71 more
```

---

So it seems to me like the testOnBorrow and/or validationQueryTimeout settings are not being enforced by the connection pool.

Comment: Are you testing with some activity that use a connection or just starting the server and waiting? If the latter is true then `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="600000"` (10 minutes) is in effect and trying to validate connections after that period but since the connection can not be established the validation query is probably never executed. Create some activity to test `testOnBorrow`. A better non-intrusive method to validate would be to capture network traffic with Wireshark or similar instead of changing server routes.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz This is how the issue was reproduced: (1) Start Tomcat - the app opens 2 DB connections in the pool when it starts up. (2) Simulate a network outage by introducing an invalid route on the DB server. (3) Send requests to the Tomcat web app so that it tries to send DB requests. -- After step #(3), Tomcat is using the connections (thread dump shows they are doing `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0`, and netstat shows packets stuck in Send-Q. So it is clear that in this scenario, testOnBorrow and validationQueryTimeout should prevail.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz you also suggest using a tcpdump - this would only allow me to see the frames, it wouldn't help simulating the network outage as an invalid route does. BTW, I still did capture a tcpdump in a previous test, and there wasn't anything to see that we don't already see from the thread dump dans netstat output. In fact, it is very clear that Tomcat just doesn't enforce its `testOnBorrow` or `validationQueryTimeout`. What's not clear to me is: *why?*

Comment: In my opinion it's not enforcing it because you didn't perform any activity on the server. testOnBorrow is activated when code requests a connection, not when pool creates them. If you want to test the pool, throw requests and check the number of connections and capture packets to see `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`in action.

Comment: Looks like I have similar issue. I got "java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed." during execution "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:308)". 
For me it looks like connection is closed and then borrowed from pool.

If connection is closed (by 'abandon mechanism' for example) but even that should be tested before borrow. It should not fail later.